# Regex for Parsing Simple Text-Based Datafile

Tags: java, regex, parsing, adventure

Can anyone give me a hand with a touch of regex?

I'm reading in a list of "locations" for a simple text adventure (those so popular back in the day). However, I'm unsure as to how to obtain the input.

The locations all follow the format:

```
<location_name>, [<item>]
    [direction, location_name]
```

Such as:

```
Albus Square, Flowers, Traffic Cone
    NORTH, Franklandclaw Lecture Theatre
    WEST, Library of Enchanted Books
    SOUTH, Furnesspuff College

Library of Enchanted Books
    EAST, Albus Square
    UP, Reading Room
```

(Subsequent locations are separated by a blank line.)

I'm storing these as Location objects with the structure:

```
public class Location {

    private String name;

    private Map<Direction, Location> links;

    private List<Item> items;

}
```

I use a method to retrieve the data from a URL and create the Location objects from the read text, but I'm at a complete block as to do this. I think regex would be of help. Can anyone lend me a well-needed hand?

Comment: Provide the format you gain data from URL. That would be a best way to find how to help you and explain how to use regexp on example provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree w/ willcodejavaforfood, regex could be used but isn't a big boost here.

Sounds like you just need a little algorithm help (sloppy p-code follows)...

```
currloc = null
while( line from file )
    if line begins w/ whitespace
        (dir, loc) = split( line, ", " )
        add dir, loc to currloc
    else
        newlocdata = split( line, ", " )
        currloc = newlocdata[0]
        for i = 1 to size( newlocdata ) - 1
            item = newlocdata[i]
            add item to currloc
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use a text-only format for this:

- What happens when you have more than a single flower item? Are they all the same? Can't an adventurer collect a bouqet at by picking single flowers at several locations?
- There will probably be several rooms with the same name ("cellar", "street corner"), i.e. filler rooms which add to the atmosphere but nothing to the game. They don't get a description of their own, though. How to keep them apart?
- What if a name contains a comma?
- Eventually, you'll want to use Unicode for foreign names or formatting instructions.

Since this is structured data which can contain lots of odd cases, I suggest to use XML for this:

```
<locations>
    <location>
        <name>Albus Square</name>
        <summary>Short description for returning adventurer</summary>
        <description>Long text here ... with formatting, etc.</description>
        <items>
            <item>Flowers</item>
            <item>Traffic Cone</item>
        <items>
        <directions>
            <north>Franklandclaw Lecture Theatre</north>
            <west>Library of Enchanted Books</west>
            <south>Furnesspuff College</south>
        </directions>
    </location>
    <location>
        <name>Library of Enchanted Books</name>
        <directions>
            <east>Albus Square</east>
            <up>Reading Room</up>
        </directions>
    </location>
</locations>
```

This allows for much greater flexibility, solves a lot of issues like formatting description text, Unicode characters, etc. plus you can use more than a single item/location with the same name by using IDs (numbers) instead of text.

Use [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/) or [DecentXML](http://code.google.com/p/decentxml/) to parse the game config.

Comment: That assumes he has control over the input format. His decription sounds like he reads some external URL, which isn't under his control.

Comment: Yes, I assume that he also writes the server since this format doesn't look like something which you can find in many places on the 'net.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, but unfortunately I do not have control over the server's data, it is just provided to me as is. Normally I would resort to using an XML format solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Can't get my head into Java-mode right now, so here's some pseudo-code that should do it:

```
Data = MyString.split('\n\n++\s*+');

for ( i=0 ; i<Data.length ; i++ )
{
    CurLocation = Data[i].split('\n\s*+');

    LocationInfo = CurLocation[0].split(',\s*+');

    LocationName = LocationInfo[0];

    for ( n=1 ; n<LocationInfo.length ; n++ )
    {
        Items[n-1] = LocationInfo[n];
    }


    for ( n=1 ; n<CurLocation.length ; n++ )
    {
        DirectionInfo = LocationInfo[n].split(',\s*+');

        DirectionName = DirectionInfo[0];

        for ( x=1 ; x<DirectionInfo.length ; x++ )
        {
            DirectionLocation[x-1] = DirectionInfo[x];
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the format of the data. That format is klunky. I suspect that you're busy reinventing the square wheel... This screems "Just use XML" to me.

Comment: But I would suspect that re-formatting the data as XML would require it to be parsed by a RegExp (Or some other technique) in the first place.

Comment: The idea is not to use text in the first place but something which is more structured.

Comment: The issue is that I do not have the data, it's at an external URL, in the text-based format outlined above. Normally I would use XML as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think using XML is overkill (shooting sparrows with cannons) while regexps are "underkill" (using a too weak tool, scrubbing floors with a toothbrush).

The right balance sounds like it's "the .ini format" or "mail headers with sections".  For python there are library docs at http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html.

A brief example:

```
[albus_square]
name: Albus Square
items: Flowers, Traffic Cone
north: lecture_theatre
west: library_enchanted_books
south: furnesspuff_college
```

I'd assume there's a Java library for this format.  As another poster has pointed out, you might have name collision so I took the liberty of adding a "name:" field.  The name in the square brackets would be the unique identifier.

Comment: Python, sweet. Wish I could use it here.